# Scaling pattern matched Kafka consumers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a scenario where there are multiple Kafka topics (single partition each) and a single consumer group to consume the records. I use a single pattern matched consumer in the consumer group that matches all the topics and hence consumes all the records in all the topics.

I now want to scale this up and have multiple consumers (in the same consumer group) listening to all the topics. However, this does not seem to be working as all the records are getting consumed only by the first consumer in the group, rendering other consumers in the group useless. Also, I am running consumers as separate threads using an `ExecutorService`.

How can I achieve this?
Below is my code:

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(topicPattern); consumer.subscribe(pattern);`

The pattern sent in the code above is such that it matches with the names of all the topics,
eg.

If topics names are `sample_topic_1`, `sample_topic_2` etc, we match it with `sample_topic_*$`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want only one consumer group?

Comment: Yes, I am limited to the number of groups that can be created, one in my case.

Comment: Limited by what?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you describe should work with the code you posted.  However, this might be a case where there's not enough data for more than one consumer.  Or maybe the data comes in "bursts" that are small enough to fit in a single batch.

Even though load in Kafka is theoretically distributed across all consumers of the same consumer group, in practice, if there is only data for one "batch", then the first consumer could grab all the data and there will be nothing left for anybody else.  This means either:

- You're not sending enough data for it to be distributed across all consumers (try sending lots more data to validate this), or
- You have a weird configuration where your configured batches are gigantic, and/or `linger.ms` property is configured very high, or
- A combination of the two above.

I suggest trying to send more data first, and seeing if that fixes the issue.  If not, try to scale back to only 1 consumer, validate it's still working.  Then just add one more consumer to that consumer group, and seeing if the behavior changes.

Comment: I increased the amount of data by around 10 times and also used multiple producer threads. I am using the default configuration that comes out of the box with Kafka.